# How to group set of tag in xsl?

Tags: xslt

I have an HTML of the following process.

```
<p class="para">First Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
<p class="pagebreak"/>
<p class="para">Second Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
<p class="pagebreak"/>
<p class="para">Third Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
```

The output should be follow below.

```
<div class="right">
   <p class="para">First Set of paragraph.</p>
   ......
   <ul>
      <li>List first</li>
      <li>List last</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="left">
   <p class="para">Second Set of paragraph.</p>
   ......
   <ul>
      <li>List first</li>
      <li>List last</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="right">
   <p class="para">Third Set of paragraph.</p>
   ......
   <ul>
     <li>List first</li>
     <li>List last</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Grouping the tag upto *class="pagebreak"*. First group is going fix to *class="right"* and Second group is going fix to *class="left"* and alternatively going on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor (like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime) to make use of `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with="p[@class = 'pagebreak']">...<./xsl:for-each-group>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using XSLT 2.0 with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9,  XmlPrime or Altova Raptor:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="p[@class = 'pagebreak']">
      <div class="{if (position() mod 2 eq 0) then 'left' else 'right'}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::p[@class = 'pagebreak'])]"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That sample transforms

```
<body>
<p class="para">First Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
<p class="pagebreak"/>
<p class="para">Second Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
<p class="pagebreak"/>
<p class="para">Third Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

into

```
<body><div class="right">
<p class="para">First Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
</div><div class="left">
<p class="para">Second Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
</div><div class="right">
<p class="para">Third Set of paragraph.</p>
......
<ul>
   <li>List first</li>
   <li>List last</li>
</ul>
</div></body>
```